# Traveling in the Nine Days

Tags: halacha, travel, vehicles-transportation, nine-days

I had heard (confirmed by [this discussion](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/18207) and [this one](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/44056)) that one may not do dangerous things during the Nine Days including "travel." Based on this: What types of travel are included? Plane? Car? Boat? Train? Walking? Bike? Hoverboard? (Etc. etc.) Does it matter how long the trip is? That is, what is the level of danger required to prohibit traveling?

Related: [Can one go on a boat during the 9 Days?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/41261/can-one-go-on-a-boat-during-the-9-days)

Comment: I wouldnt consider it at all confirmed that one may not tranvel during the nine days. Certainly not when the only source for this seems to be a second hand version of a 20th century source. There is certainly tremendous room to question this, and I personally heard a posek make light of it. Additionally, it should be noted that Rambam and others were opposed to these sorts of astrological fears. See [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/57438/8775) and [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/53765/8775).

Comment: @mevaqesh Nobody addressed air travel prior to the 20th century because it didn't yet exist. R' Auerbach was disinclined to travel by air then because he felt it fit into the practice mentioned by some poskim to be more cautious about danger during that period (e.g. Shulchan Aruch OC 551:18). And is this definitely an "astrological fear"? It's not an inherent astrological concern about the time of the year, but rather that time is thought to be set aside for punishment due to the sin of the spies at that time (e.g. per *Ta'anis* 29a, "ובשניה מנלן דתניא מגלגלין זכות ליום זכאי וחובה ליום חייב").

Comment: @Fred Exactly. something that only came into existence in the 20th century will by nature be less ceratinly classified by halakha than something already addressed by Torah Shbiktav, or Sheb'al Peh. The belief that certain times are lucky or unlucky is intimately associated with astrology. This is how such passages in the Talmud are almost universally classically interpreted (and hence all omitted by Rambam who does not believe in astrology). Even the passage you quote (which I wouldn't assume  is at all representative) is just a more "religious" expression of the belief in lucky times.

Answer (score -1):

Lich'orah, anything that you would need to say T'fillas HaDerech for.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeia, user13094. I highly recommend that you [edit](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/75182/edit) your answer to make it a bit more substantial and rooted in sources, and check out the [FAQ](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on the topic. Hope to see you around a bit, and I hope you enjoy your stay.